# How to use a Fingerprint Sensor to Login to windows programs that ask for a username and password?

Tags: windows, script, login, active-directory, fingerprint

There are Windows programs that ask for a username and password but don't allow alternatives like Fingerprint login.
In my specific case, i have a POS (Point of Sales) that needs to be used by different persons.
There's a feature for automatic logout after each transaction, so it would be convenient to login with a Fingerprint.

- I tried to find out if fingerprint readers come with software that allows to trigger scripts after a finger is authenticated.
  I imagined scripts to work like "if window x has focus, fill in login data"...
  But i did not find anything that seems to do such a job.
- I found out that RoboForm, a Password manager, can attach itself to the login window of my application, and fill in user/password when you click on the roboform extension. There's an option to use windows biometric login to log into Roboform, but that's only for logging into RoboForm.
- What my program does have, is integration with Active Directory, something i never used before. But as far as i see, this only allows to use passwords defined in AD. The manufacturer advertises this as a way to enforce password policies.

What could be other approaches or solutions to that login-problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the only Software that i could find, which would do what i want, is

https://www.m2sys.com/biosnapon/

They sell a **Hamster Pro 20** Reader and the Software with a 50-User license for around $200. Or for a bit less without the Hardware.

It works smoothly, but has a few quirks:

- It only operates with a narrow selection of specific fingerprint readers.
- It was very complicated to install, with a client- and a server- component, with confusing documentation but good mail support.
- It does not have a full user interface for managing registered fingers and users. Either you keep track of that data on your own, or you need a tool to go into the database (uses an MS access DB by default, but can be configured to MySql, etc.).

I investigated a handful of other Password Managers like 1Password, but as of now, they all work like RoboForm, only using fingerprint login to get into the manager, not to trigger form-fill's.

If you know an alternative approach to fingerprint login, please let me know.